# Quadratic equation with weighted average coefficients

Tags: quadratics

I have tried using the quadratic formula as well as factoring method to solve the following quadratic equation but failed to get the correct answer.

The equation is:  $$   \theta x^2-x+(1-\theta)=0.$$

Note: the coefficient is theta

How to go ahead? What would be the two roots?

Comment: $x=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1-4\theta(1-\theta)}}{2}= \frac{1\pm (1-2\theta)}{2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\theta x^2-x+(1-\theta)=\theta (x^2-1)-(x-1)=(x-1)[\theta(x+1)-1]$

Comment: Makes sense, eventually, we get x=1 and x=1-θ/θ

Answer (score 0):

$θx^2-x+(1-θ)=0$

Using, $x = \frac{-b \pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$

$x =\frac{-(-1) \pm\sqrt{(-1)^2-4\theta (1-\theta)}}{2\theta} = \frac{1 \pm\sqrt{1-4\theta +4\theta^2}}{2\theta} = \frac{1 \pm\sqrt{(1-2\theta)^2}}{2\theta} = \frac{1 \pm (1 - 2\theta) }{2} = (1- \theta) \ or \ \theta$